# Is there a way to associate a description with database snapshot?

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

Is there a way to associate a description with database snapshot?

I usually name snapshots using original database name and timestamp:

**DBName-05-27-2016_1018**

I would like to be able to associate a comment like "Before executing schema update scripts related to feature NNN" with a snapshot.

This is something that I could put in database extended properties but since snapshot is read-only it is not possible after it is created and it doesn't look like extended properties can be specified as a part of snapshot creation. Making these comments a part of snapshot name is ugly.

Is there any other way to associate a metadata with database snapshot when it is created? Of course I can maintain a table in separate utility database just for this but this is not too convenient.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way to associate a metadata with database snapshot when it is created?

No. Since a database snapshot is **read-only**, you cannot modify or add any settings to it. In-fact, extended properties cannot be applied to it.

So your best option is to have a table in the database (or a utility database) called e.g. `dbo.database_snapshot_history` with columns like `servername, databasename, snapshotname, createBY, createdate`